# Django, бот. Работа на сервере

Tags: python, django, бот

Здравствуйте. Создал бот для вк на python, работает. Как сделать так, чтоб он работал с сервера Django и записывал данные в базу данных?

Comment: Может, приведёте конкретный код, свои идеи? За вас с нуля никто ничего писать тут не будет.

Comment: Ну, очевидно, что нужно выложить его на сервер и дописать код, который будет писать в базу. А подробнее на такой неконкретный вопрос никто не сможет ответить.